# Strikethrough horizontal line with words in the middle Swift iOS

Tags: swift5, strikethrough, nsattributedstringkey

I am trying to get this done using `AttributedString`.

Is there a way to have horizontal line with words in the middle?

[image: I need similar to this]

Comment: you can achieve this  by using three label with auto-layout.

Comment: @balkaransingh You are totally right, but my method to build that cell in a message application, force me to use AttributedString. Thats why I asked for AttributedString.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using three label with auto-layout

[image]

i give constraint to center label(Today 08.30) center horizontal and center vertical to viewcontroller.

[image]

just **change the Hugging Priority** of center label(Today 08.30) to 1000
[image]

now your center label adjust his width accoding to your text.

give backboard color to other two label.

Comment: You are totally right, but my method to build that cell in a message application, force me to use ```AttributedString```. Thats why I asked for AttributedString.